# Is their an official macOS download for virtual machines?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, virtual-machine, macos

I want to use Xcode to develop iOS apps, but I only have a laptop with Windows software, and I know about virtual machines like VirtualBox and VMware, so I wondered: "Is their an **official** way to get MacOS for virtual machines?", I only want a **legal** way or you could say an **official** way, otherwise I won't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't any special download for virtual machines.

However, this doesn't really matter if you specifically want a legal option, because you couldn't legally run it on your laptop anyway unless the hardware is made by Apple, as there is an explicit clause in the licensing for macOS that requires that it only be run on Apple hardware (note that this doesn't prevent you from virtualizing it legally, you just have to run the virtual machine on Apple hardware).

Comment: This Answer is correct: Apple allows the more recent versions of macOS to run within a virtual machine in a VM tool such as Parallels, Fusion, or VirtualBox. But Apple requires the physical host machine be a Mac. I do this myself for development and texting purposes. I simply use the regular macOS installer app from Apple with Parallels. Works surprisingly well, even supporting Retina mode lately. But you cannot legally run macOS on non-Apple hardware either directly or through a VM.